# AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'on_voice_state_update'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
Client = discord.Client(intents=intents)



@Client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged in as", Client.user.name)
    VC = Client.get_channel(917198277148041241)
    members = VC.members
    memids = []
    discord.on_voice_state_update(memids)
    for member in members:
        memids.append(member.id)
        memids.append(member.name)



Client.run(Token)
```

The issue comes at discord.on_voice_state_update(memids) and I get a attribute error

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [`on_voice_state_update`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_voice_state_update#discord.on_voice_state_update) event, use it like this:

```py
@Client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(before, after):
    pass  # whatever here
```

`before` and `after` are [voice states](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=voicestate#discord.VoiceState) of member.